# one session factory for multiple schemas

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on an application that has multiple schemas. Now we are planning to use hibernate in dao layer.

Is it fine, if we have one session factory for all the schemas. On entities I will specify the schema name.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that is a perfectly legit setup.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So one session factory can cover multiple schemas as long as schema name is mentioned on each entity right. Your answer is very valuable to me.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely why the `javax.persistence.Table` annotation has a `schema` attribute so that you can spread your entities across various schemas (or tablespaces if you're using Oracle).